# How do I create an accordion box using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want is this:

```
Start:                        End:
----------------          ----------------
|asdf          |          |              |
----------------          |   stuff      |
                          |              |
                          |              |
                          ----------------
                          |     asdf     |  
                          ----------------
```

When you click asdf it should end up looking like the End box but the 'stuff' box should appear gradually so it looks like the asdf box is pulling down the stuff menu. When asdf is clicked again it should look like the stuff box is pulling up the asdf box and end at the Start position.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this may be heavier of a solution than you'd like (or you don't wish to use jQuery at all) but you may want to consider the [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/).

**Update:** [Here is a pretty detailed jQuery UI Accordion tutorial](http://www.packtpub.com/article/jquery-ui-accordion-widget-part1) by Dan Wellman at Packt.

**Update 2:** If you're not sold on using jQuery UI, [here is a tutorial covering how to build an accordion with just the base jQuery library](http://www.queness.com/post/741/a-simple-and-beautiful-jquery-accordion-tutorial).

Comment: Is there an accordion box that works for just one box?  Instead of having more than one, its just a box with a title, you click the title and the content drops down, click it again, and it hides the content?

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you want to re-invent the wheel, you'll need to set up a function that's called periodically (via the setTimeout(), clearTimeout() or setInterval() and clearInterval()  functions) to control the animation after establishing the state (open or closed) via a onclick handler.

However, the vast majority of people would just use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or one of the other well known JavaScript frameworks, hence saving time and energy for other areas of functionality.